# Drupal: How to get a CCK field value when inserting a node?

Tags: drupal, cck

I'm working on a registration system where someone can enter the number of participants they will be bringing in a CCK field. I want to, whenever a node type with that CCK field is added, grab the value of that field, then add it to a variable value I have in my variables table.

Is the CCK value inserted into the field's table in the db prior to my custom module running something when $op is "insert" for hook_nodeapi? Or is there some other way to directly grab the value of that field?

Comment: I don't fully understand you. If you're in hook_nodeapi > insert, you should have access to the values in the submitted form, and at that point can write a query (or use variable_get/set) to update your table.

Comment: I was originally going to do that, but finally decided to use Rules. Rules is pretty powerful!

Comment: I was just about to research all of this, when I saw you mention rules. That's all I need to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved this: I used the Rules module, and set up a ruleset to update the number of reserved registration spots by SUM-ing the CCK field containing each group's number reserved. Then I created rules for node additions, updates, and deletions, so the number auto-updates at all times.

It was much easier than using hook_nodeapi, and will be much easier to maintain...

Answer (score 0):

yes, hook_nodeapi. But it's not good way to save users data to variables data (each new user add new row for variables). Just keep it in cck fields.

Comment: It sounds to me like he's keeping a running total of registrants or something. If he's adding to some other table, or a value in the variable table with the value of a cck field, he could just be updating a single value every time.

Comment: i think, it for storing some other value. Count of users easy take from via querying users table. For asker: be clear...

Comment: sprugman had it right - I was trying to keep a total of registrants, and to get that, I wanted to allow users to give an arbitrary number of registrants per group.

Comment: Count of registrants? select count(*) from users? For why when this field?

Comment: It's not a listing of individual registrants, but a group system, where individuals can reserve an arbitrary number of spots (thus the field).